# What is the substitution ratio for mini marshmallows to large marshmallows?

Tags: substitutions, measurements, marshmallow

I have a recipe calling for 12 large marshmallows, but I only have minis. How many should I use?

Comment: I don't know if "mini" and "large" are actually standard sizes/weights across all brands; isn't there a serving size printed on the package?

Answer (score 7):

Kraft's Jet-Puffed brand claims the following conversion factor:

> 1 Regular Marshmallow = 13 Mini Marshmallows

That puts you at around 156 Mini Marshmallows for 12 Regulars.

Comment: @Vicki: Haha have fun counting them all...

Comment: Packing density being sensitive to shape, but not so much to size, 2 cups of big Marshmallows should contain about the same mass of marshmallow as 2 cups of small Marshmallows.

Answer (score 5):

This [nutrition data](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/sweets/5425/2) says that:

- 1 cup of miniature marshmallows weighs 50 grams,
- 10 miniature marshmallows weigh 7 grams, and
- 1 regular marshmallow weighs 7 grams

1:10 is a bit different from [Sam Ley's answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/21764/1672); maybe Kraft is a little off average or this data is a little off. In any case, it's helpful in that it'd let you measure: 12 large ("regular") would be 84 grams, which is almost exactly 1 2/3 cups.

Comment: Good data - I'm sure that "mini" and "regular" aren't internationally recognized SI units. ;) Somewhere in the 1:10 range is probably good for most brands, though you'll invariably have to eyeball it a bit and judge whether your dish is sufficiently mallow-y.

Comment: Thank You I found this site extremely helpful. I only had the mini marshmallows and was at loss since this was my first time having to substitute. I used the 1 2/3 cup and it worked perfectly give or take a few marsh mellows!.