# Can I substitute a 10 oz bag of large marshmallows for the same weight equivalent in miniature mallows?

Tags: substitutions

My recipe calls for a 10 oz bag of miniature marshmallows. I only have a 10oz bag of regular marshmallows (not jet-puffed), will that work?  Thank you.

Comment: It might be worth adding a few details on the recipe to give some ideas on why the original recipe may have asked for miniature marshmallows in particular.

Comment: Depending on use, you might have to cut the large MMs into smallish pieces - which can be messy. I suggest scissors. But overall, heed @PeterJ's advice and post the recipe / intended use here. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Takes the bigger ones longer to melt, and they're a mouthfull all on their own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the substitution ratio for mini marshmallows to large marshmallows?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21763/what-is-the-substitution-ratio-for-mini-marshmallows-to-large-marshmallows)

Answer (score 3):

Culinarily speaking, large marshmallows are identical ounce-for-ounce to miniature marshmallows, so for the purpose of an ingredient substitution, this should not cause you a problem. But there are a few things to consider:

Miniature marshmallows are obviously smaller… so if your recipe calls for using them whole, you may have to decide if the larger versions are appropriate for your recipe.

Miniature marshmallows are also easier to melt, so if you are adding larger pieces to a hot mixture, you may have to take extra care they are melting completely. And if you are melting them over heat, be sure the extra time required does not cause them to burn.

And just for the sake of completeness, marshmallows are also coated in corn starch to prevent them from sticking to one another. Since miniature marshmallows have a bit more surface area, you may end up with just a bit less cornstarch in your mixture. But it seems *highly* unlikely this will make a difference in your final product.