# Mini vs regular marshmallows

Tags: marshmallow

I have a recipe that calls for 500 grams of mini marshmallows.  I only have regular marshmallows (340 grams in bag).  Does anyone know how many regular marshmallows I would need?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21763/what-is-the-substitution-ratio-for-mini-marshmallows-to-large-marshmallows?rq=1

Comment: I have trouble understanding the question. If you need 500 g marshmallows, then that's how many you should use. The mini vs regular marshmallow doesn't change anything about that.

Comment: @Cindy disagree with the dupe. (Related, yes.) The values given in the other Q/A aren’t consistent and there’s no compelling reason that marshmallows would come in standard weights. I certainly observed some variation in “regular” ones. Not necessarily much or crucial, but if the recipe already gives weight...

Answer (score 5):

The nice thing about recipes that are using weight instead volume or numbers is that you can **simply use scales to weigh the amount you need**.

If you absolutely don’t have a scale, I recommend you count the number of marshmallows in the pack, then determine how much one weighs. From there, it should be easy to calculate how many you need to get 500g or how many from a second pack you still need to add.

> So one marshmallow weighs:
> [340 : (number of marshmallows in the pack)] g.
>
> You still need:
> [ 160 : (weight of one marshmallow)] marshmallows.
> (Using the previously determined weight.)

If your calculations give you a fraction of a marshmallow, either cut one (eyeballing is probably fine) or round to the nearest whole number.

Comment: OK, if that's where the confusion behind the question comes from, I would suggest, in this specific case, to use one and a half bags of marshmallows. Theoretically, that would be 510 g, not 500, so the math is wrong. Practically, labelling laws frequently allow 5% under/overfilling of food packages, and recipes are rarely sensitive to such narrow margins.

Comment: I can think of a possible exception: If they're to be spread in a single layer such as topping a cake of known size (unlikely for marshmallows perhaps, but common for some other things).  But otherwise definitely just match the weight

Comment: @ChrisH unless the recipe absolutely needs mini marshmallows for decorative purposes, cutting the large ones may also work.

Comment: @Stephie that too